# Are there any problems with giving both vw and vh properties for a single tag?

Tags: css, viewport-units

I have included the property as given below in the CSS:

```
p {
   font-size: 2.5vw; 
   font-size: 2.5vh;
}
```

Does this create any issues?

Comment: NO...........it will consider second font-size

Comment: It might be helpful to learn [what CSS means](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+css&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS576US576&oq=what+is+css&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j69i59j69i65l2j69i60.1577j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the value will simply be 2.5vh since it comes later. There is no special cascading behavior for any particular unit.

Comment: what is required to activate both the width and height parameters?

Comment: @anandmbs It is not possible to manually adjust the width and height of a font. You can only scale the size proportionally.